# How can this "illegal geometry" problem be possible?

Tags: geometry

Using 2 triangles each with base of 8 and height of 3, and 2 trapezoids with heights of 3 on top, 5 on bottom and height of 5, these four figures can create an area with 64 units squared. However, when rearranged as a rectangle with 13 x 5=65, one additional unit squared seemed to have been created. How is this possible?

[image]

Comment: This is the [missing square puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_square_puzzle).

Comment: so the second figure has triangles slightly bigger than the triangles in figure one?

Comment: also, unlike the wikipedia article, the hypothenuse is completely and utterly straight: http://prntscr.com/gg199b

Comment: @GoodwinLu then it doesn't work, the truth is it's not possible it's an illusion.

Comment: According to the figure on the right, $\frac25=\frac38$. Who knew?

Answer (score 13):

Here's a slightly less subtle "demonstration" that a rectangle with area 5 can be rearranged into a rectangle with area 6.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nicely done (+1).

Answer (score 6):

This is a classic illusion based on the Fibonacci number identity
$$
13 \times 5 = 1 + 8 \times 8 .
$$

The "diagonal" of the rectangle isn't one. The slopes on each segment don't agree. There's one unit of  area between the "diagonals".

Answer (score 3):

> unlike the wikipedia article, the hypothenuse is completely and utterly straight

No, it's not. Consider the bottom-left corner of the rectangle.

- Let $\alpha$ be the angle in the yellow triangle, then $\tan \alpha = 3/8\,$.
- Let $\beta$ be the angle in the green trapezoid, then $\tan \beta = 5/(5-3)=5/2\,$.

But then $\,\tan \alpha \tan \beta = 15 / 16 \ne 1\,$, so $\,\alpha+\beta \ne 90^\circ\,$ i.e. the two angles do not add up to a right angle. The slopes of the two hypotenuses differ by $\,90^\circ - \arctan 3/8 - \arctan 5/2 \simeq 1.25 ^\circ$.

Comment: In fact, not only is the "hypotenuse" not straight, it is bent in _exactly the same way_ as in the Wikipedia article: part of the "hypotenuse" has slope 2/5, and the rest of it has slope 3/8.

Comment: @DavidK Indeed, and also thanks for the pointer to that cute animation in the duplicate link. Somewhat related: [the perpetual chocolate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/743074).